# Are these correct definitions for a quantity called 'center of shape'?

Tags: mass

Today, I thought of a new quantity. I don't have a proof but I think it should give the geometrical center of any body.
The position vector of the center of shape of any body is given by the sum of the position vectors of all the particles constituting the body divided by the number of particles constituting the body. I couldn't think of a definition for continuous bodies, but I think in case of continuous bodies, it is given by the integration of the product of an infinitesimally small mass element, dm with its position vector over the whole body when the density of the bpdy is assumed to be constant even if it is a variable. I think these definitions should make sense. And, the center of shape should coincide with the center of mass when the body has constant density. Are these definitions correct? And, is this quantity of any use in architechture or something like that?

Comment: I fail to see how this quantity is different from center of mass. Perhaps you could show an example where they differ?

Comment: @user37496: As I said, this quantity coincides with the center of mass only for bodies of constant density. For example, for a rectangular plate, it its density increases from left to right, it's center of mass is towards the right while its center of dhape is still at the point of intersection of its diagonals, i.e. at the point of symmetry.

Comment: What you are describing is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), which is a mathematical concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continuos bodies an integral equation is better than a summation.
It sounds like you have essentially a center-of-mass definition with the mass taken out, I've no doubt that's correct.

Center of mass is incredibly useful whenever any kind of question about balance comes up.

Every kind of movement or acceleration has to consider inertia due to mass, so any calculation around moving or balancing the object will use center of mass.

Center of shape can be used for cosmetic purposes, to get things to look centered, and may be a first aproximation to center of mass if the mass distribution is unknown.